# javascript game enemies and player are invisible no errors

Tags: javascript, error-handling, game-physics, game-development, spawning

iam trying to recreate supercrate box on a webpage but somehow my enemies and my player are invisible

this the code

```
/ Get the canvas element and context
const canvas = document.getElementById('game_canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Set the canvas width and height
canvas.width = 800;
canvas.height = 600;


// Crate properties
let crate = {
  x: Math.random() * (canvas.width - 30),
  y: Math.random() * (canvas.height - 200),
  width: 30,
  height: 30,
  weapons: ['Weapon1', 'Weapon2', 'Weapon3', /* ... and other weapons */],
  currentWeapon: '',
};

// Enemies
const enemies = [];
const enemySpeed = 2;

// Function to handle enemy spawning
function spawnEnemy() {
    const enemy = {
      x: canvas.width / 2 - 10 + Math.random() * 20, // Spawn at the hole on top
      y: -30,
      width: 20 + Math.random() * 20,
      height: 20 + Math.random() * 20,
      speedX: 0,
      speedY: enemySpeed + Math.random() * 2,
    };
    enemies.push(enemy);
  }
  
  function checkCollision(rect1, rect2) {
    return (
      rect1.x < rect2.x + rect2.width &&
      rect1.x + rect1.width > rect2.x &&
      rect1.y < rect2.y + rect2.height &&
      rect1.y + rect1.height > rect2.y
    );
  }
  
  // Function to check if a point (x, y) is inside a rectangle
  function pointInsideRect(x, y, rect) {
    return x >= rect.x && x <= rect.x + rect.width && y >= rect.y && y <= rect.y + rect.height;
  }
  const ENEMY_TYPES = {
    SMALL: 'small',
    BIG: 'big',
    FLYING: 'flying',
  };
  
  // Function to create an enemy object
  function createEnemy(x, y, type) {
    const enemy = {
      x,
      y,
      type,
      width: type === ENEMY_TYPES.BIG ? 40 : 30,
      height: type === ENEMY_TYPES.BIG ? 40 : 30,
      speedX: 0,
      speedY: type === ENEMY_TYPES.FLYING ? 2 * (Math.random() - 0.5) : 0, // For flying enemy, random initial diagonal speed
      speed: type === ENEMY_TYPES.SMALL ? 5 : type === ENEMY_TYPES.BIG ? 2 : 1,
      bounceCount: 0, // To track the number of times small enemy bounces off the bottom hole
    };
    enemies.push(enemy);
  }
  
  // Function to move enemies
  function moveEnemies() {
    for (const enemy of enemies) {
      enemy.x += enemy.speedX * enemy.speed;
      enemy.y += enemy.speedY * enemy.speed;
  
      // Small enemy behavior
      if (enemy.type === ENEMY_TYPES.SMALL) {
        // Check collisions with the floor and the borders
        if (enemy.y + enemy.height > canvas.height - 40) {
          // Collided with the floor or bottom border
          if (enemy.bounceCount === 0) {
            enemy.y = canvas.height - 40 - enemy.height;
            enemy.speedY *= -1; // Reverse the vertical speed to bounce off
            enemy.bounceCount++; // Increase the bounce count
          } else {
            // Teleport back to the spawn point and increase speed
            enemy.x = canvas.width / 2 - 10 + Math.random() * 20;
            enemy.y = -30;
            enemy.speedY = 5;
          }
        }
        if (enemy.x + enemy.width > canvas.width - 40 || enemy.x < 40) {
          // Collided with the left or right border
          enemy.speedX *= -1; // Reverse the horizontal speed to bounce off
        }
      }
  
      // Big enemy behavior
      if (enemy.type === ENEMY_TYPES.BIG) {
        if (enemy.y + enemy.height > canvas.height - 40) {
          // Collided with the floor or bottom border
          if (enemy.bounceCount === 0) {
            enemy.y = canvas.height - 40 - enemy.height;
            enemy.speedY *= -1; // Reverse the vertical speed to bounce off
            enemy.bounceCount++; // Increase the bounce count
          } else {
            // Teleport back to the spawn point and increase speed
            enemy.x = canvas.width / 2 - 10 + Math.random() * 20;
            enemy.y = -30;
            enemy.speedY = 2;
          }
        }
        if (enemy.x + enemy.width > canvas.width - 40 || enemy.x < 40) {
          // Collided with the left or right border
          enemy.speedX *= -1; // Reverse the horizontal speed to bounce off
        }
      }
  
      // Flying enemy behavior
      if (enemy.type === ENEMY_TYPES.FLYING) {
        // Check collisions with the walls
        if (enemy.x + enemy.width > canvas.width - 40 || enemy.x < 40) {
          // Collided with the left or right wall
          enemy.speedX *= -1; // Reverse the horizontal speed to change direction
        }
        if (enemy.y + enemy.height > canvas.height - 40 || enemy.y < 40) {
          // Collided with the top or bottom wall
          enemy.speedY *= -1; // Reverse the vertical speed to change direction
        }
      }
    }
  }

  const player = {
    x: canvas.width / 2,
    y: canvas.height / 2, // Place the player in the middle of the canvas
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
    speed: 5,
    jumpHeight: 12,
    isJumping: false,
    canJump: true,
  };
  
  // Function to handle enemy spawning
  function spawnEnemy() {
    const enemy = {
      x: canvas.width / 2 - 10 + Math.random() * 20, // Spawn at the end of the first hole
      y: -30,
      width: 20 + Math.random() * 20,
      height: 20 + Math.random() * 20,
      speedX: 0,
      speedY: enemySpeed + Math.random() * 2,
    };
    enemies.push(enemy);
  }

  function handlePlayerMovement() {
    // Left movement (A key)
    if (keys['a'] && player.x > 40) {
      player.x -= player.speed;
    }
  
    // Right movement (D key)
    if (keys['d'] && player.x < canvas.width - player.width - 40) {
      player.x += player.speed;
    }
  
    // Jumping (W key)
    if (keys['w']) {
      if (!player.isJumping && player.canJump) {
        player.isJumping = true;
        player.canJump = false;
        player.speedY = -player.jumpHeight;
      }
    } else {
      // Reset jump state when W key is released
      player.isJumping = false;
    }
  
    // Gravity for player
    player.speedY += 0.5;
    player.y += player.speedY;
  
     // Check collisions with the floor and the top border
  if (player.y + player.height > canvas.height - 40) {
    // Collided with the floor or bottom border
    player.y = canvas.height - 40 - player.height;
    player.canJump = true; // Allow jumping again
    player.speedY = 0; // Reset vertical speed
  }
  if (player.y < 40) {
    // Collided with the top border
    player.y = 40;
    player.speedY = 0; // Reset vertical speed
  }
    
    // Check collisions with platforms
    const platforms = [
      { x: canvas.width * 0.2, y: canvas.height * 0.8, width: canvas.width * 0.6, height: 10 },
      { x: 0, y: canvas.height * 0.5, width: canvas.width * 0.2, height: 10 },
      { x: canvas.width * 0.8, y: canvas.height * 0.5, width: canvas.width * 0.2, height: 10 },
      { x: canvas.width * 0.2, y: canvas.height * 0.2, width: canvas.width * 0.6, height: 10 },
    ];
  
    for (const platform of platforms) {
      if (
        player.y + player.height > platform.y &&
        player.y < platform.y + platform.height &&
        player.x + player.width > platform.x &&
        player.x < platform.x + platform.width &&
        player.speedY > 0
      ) {
        // Collided with the platform from the top
        player.y = platform.y - player.height;
        player.canJump = true; // Allow jumping again
        player.speedY = 0; // Reset vertical speed
      }
    }
  }
  
  // Function to handle shooting (space bar)
  function handleShooting() {
    // Your shooting logic goes here
    // ...
  }
  
  // Keyboard input
  const keys = {};
  
  // Event listeners for keyboard input
  window.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    keys[event.key.toLowerCase()] = true;
  
    // Handle shooting (space bar)
    if (event.key.toLowerCase() === ' ') {
      handleShooting();
    }
  });
  
  window.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
    keys[event.key.toLowerCase()] = false;
  });
  
// Game loop
function gameLoop() {
    // Clear the canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // Draw the black walls around the level
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // Draw the room border with a white stroke
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
    ctx.lineWidth = 6;
    ctx.strokeRect(20, 20, canvas.width - 40, canvas.height - 40);

    // Draw the two holes on top in the center (where enemies spawn) with borders
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillRect(canvas.width / 2 - 55, 0, 110, 40);
    ctx.fillRect(canvas.width / 2 - 15, 0, 30, 20);

    // Draw the hole on the other side (where the fire is) with a border
    const holeWidth = 100; // Set the width of the second hole
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillRect(canvas.width / 2 - holeWidth / 2, canvas.height - 30, holeWidth, 30);
  
    // Draw the platforms (Moved up to be behind everything else)
    ctx.fillStyle = '#ccc';
    ctx.fillRect(canvas.width * 0.2, canvas.height * 0.8, canvas.width * 0.6, 10);
    ctx.fillRect(0, canvas.height * 0.5, canvas.width * 0.2, 10);
    ctx.fillRect(canvas.width * 0.8, canvas.height * 0.5, canvas.width * 0.2, 10);
    ctx.fillRect(canvas.width * 0.2, canvas.height * 0.2, canvas.width * 0.6, 10);
  
    /// Draw the player
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);

    // Draw the crate
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fillRect(crate.x, crate.y, crate.width, crate.height);

    // Draw enemies
    ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
    for (const enemy of enemies) {
      ctx.fillRect(enemy.x, enemy.y, enemy.width, enemy.height);
    }

  // Update the game state here (e.g., handle player movement, collisions, crate pickup, etc.)

  // Handle player movement (You need to implement this)
  handlePlayerMovement();
  // Move enemies
  moveEnemies();
  // Check for crate pickup
  if (
    player.x < crate.x + crate.width &&
    player.x + player.width > crate.x &&
    player.y < crate.y + crate.height &&
    player.y + player.height > crate.y
  ) {
    // Pick up crate and get a random weapon
    const randomWeaponIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * crate.weapons.length);
    crate.currentWeapon = crate.weapons[randomWeaponIndex];
    score++; // Increase the score for each crate picked up
    crate.x = Math.random() * (canvas.width - 30);
    crate.y = Math.random() * (canvas.height - 200);
  }

  // Check for collisions with enemies (You need to implement this)

  // Handle enemy spawning
  if (Math.random() < 0.01) {
    spawnEnemy();
  }

  // Move enemies downwards
for (const enemy of enemies) {
    enemy.x += enemy.speedX;
    enemy.y += enemy.speedY;
  
    // Check collisions with the floor and the borders
    if (enemy.y + enemy.height > canvas.height - 40) {
      // Collided with the floor or bottom border
      enemy.y = canvas.height - 40 - enemy.height;
      enemy.speedY *= -1; // Reverse the vertical speed to bounce off
    }
    if (enemy.y < 40) {
      // Collided with the top border
      enemy.y = 40;
      enemy.speedY *= -1; // Reverse the vertical speed to bounce off
    }
    if (enemy.x + enemy.width > canvas.width - 40 || enemy.x < 40) {
      // Collided with the left or right border
      enemy.speedX *= -1; // Reverse the horizontal speed to bounce off
    }

    // Check collisions with the player (You need to implement this)
    // ...

    // Check if the enemy is inside a platform
    const platform1 = { x: canvas.width * 0.2, y: canvas.height * 0.8, width: canvas.width * 0.6, height: 10 };
    const platform2 = { x: 0, y: canvas.height * 0.5, width: canvas.width * 0.2, height: 10 };
    const platform3 = { x: canvas.width * 0.8, y: canvas.height * 0.5, width: canvas.width * 0.2, height: 10 };
    const platform4 = { x: canvas.width * 0.2, y: canvas.height * 0.2, width: canvas.width * 0.6, height: 10 };

    if (
      pointInsideRect(enemy.x + enemy.width / 2, enemy.y + enemy.height, platform1) ||
      pointInsideRect(enemy.x + enemy.width / 2, enemy.y + enemy.height, platform2) ||
      pointInsideRect(enemy.x + enemy.width / 2, enemy.y + enemy.height, platform3) ||
      pointInsideRect(enemy.x + enemy.width / 2, enemy.y + enemy.height, platform4)
    ) {
      // If the enemy is inside a platform, allow it to pass through
      enemy.speedY = 0;
    }
  }

  
  // Request the next animation frame
  requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}

// Start the game loop
window.onload = () => {
    gameLoop();
  };
```

there are no misstakes in the browser console and the html and css is proberly linked the weird think is that once i use the movement key of the player one enemie sometimes shows up and disapears instanlyy